# Android - Build failed with an exception while running react-native run-android

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native, react-native-fcm

I am trying to setup remote push notifications in react-native and I am using the react-native-fcm package for fulling that.I followed the guide in setting up the required things from the github page of the package .I keep running in to the following error and I am not sure what is missing or if I am doing something wrong .

Error :

```
:app:processDebugResources
 C:\Users\test\Desktop\App_Dev\pushNotifyDev\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:58:31-47: 
AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@mipmap/ic_notif').

C:\Users\test\Desktop\App_Dev\pushNotifyDev\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@mipmap/ic_notif').


:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.121 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pushnotifydev"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notif"/>

      <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </service>

      <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.InstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </service>


      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am using the following 
React-native -0.53
Android Studio -3.0.1

Any help in debugging this would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks